# Test that an AsyncTask was started using Robolectric

Tags: android, android-asynctask, robolectric

I have an `Activity` which is supposed to start an `AsyncTask` and I would like to test this behavior using Robolectric 3.0.

So far, I do it this way but I'm not really happy with it:

```
@Test
public void testAsyncTaskIsStarted() {
    activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MyActivity.class);
    Assert.assertTrue(ShadowApplication.getInstance().getBackgroundThreadScheduler().areAnyRunnable());
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As for me better test would be to run this background task and check something happened

Comment: Yes but the whole point of unit testing is to test components individually. This way I don't depend on the task behavior, especially if my AsyncTask is doing http requests or other operations I have to mock.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't understand that that you are not interested in task result but only interested that some abstract code will be run in another thread. Even more explicit it is going to be run over `AsyncTask`. I would recommend to look to another injection way (Dagger 2 is my choice)

Answer (score 0):

I finally did this by mocking my `AsyncTask` with Mockito.
In my `Activity` , I extracted my `AsyncTask`as a class field in order to be able to mock it:

```
public void MyActivity extends Activity {
    MyAsyncTask task;

    public void onCreate (...) {
        ...
        if (task == null)
            task = new MyAsyncTask();

        task.execute(...);
        ...
    }
```

And in my tests:

```
MyAsyncTask asyncTaskMock = Mockito.mock(MyAsyncTask.class);    

@Test
public void testAsyncTaskIsStarted() {
    controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class);
    controller.get().task = asyncTaskMock;
    controller.create().resume().visible();

    Mockito.verify(asyncTaskMock).execute(...);
}
```

Hope this helps.